# Qemu backup software?

Tags: backup, kvm, qemu

I have a self build NAS (Debian) which is running about 5 VM's for different things (NAS, VPN, Time Machine, Media etc). The Host is a bare Debian install. VM's are managed using virsh in the command line or virt-manager within the GUI.

All data is stored within the VM and currently, I back the VM's nightly to a USB3 external hard disk.

I'd like a better way (possibly incremental) backup solution for my VM's but so far am struggling to find any real solution (software based) for Linux.

Is creating a simple snapshot of the VM really the only way to do this? I am more used to Hyper-V and an image manager to backup and merge backups into a single, restorable image file so would like to see this on Linux.

Can anyone please suggest the best way to backup my VM's? Ideally, I'd like incremental so I can eventually make cloud backups which will be quicker than a full VM copy.

I'd prefer a GUI, just because I find it easier to make sure the VM's are being backed up correctly but wouldn't mind a reliable command line type system.

I have Google'd the hell out of this over the last few weeks so please Linux guru's, make my day!